# SQL connector installation trouble on El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-connector

Having a 10.11.1 Mac OS, I am today trying to install ODBC connector: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-osx10.11-x86-64bit.dmg

However, the install fails and I cannot understand why (message asks to request the editor :)

Has anyone faced that issue and fixed it?

Thanks in advance,

Loic

Comment: What is the **exact** error?

Comment: The installations progress stops saying there were errors and I need to get in touch with the editor : http://s29.postimg.org/6jjpiw9xi/Capture_d_e_cran_2016_04_07_a_16_33_06.jpg

Comment: My French isn't the greatest, but "The program encountered an error when installing. Contact its author for more help". Stackoveflow is **not** the author -- that would be the [MySQL project](https://dev.mysql.com),  who helpfully provide a [bug tracker](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-support-bug-report.html). Please use that.

Comment: You are right. I will do but thought some folk here could have faced the same issue and hopefully fixed it.

Comment: If you followed the instructions on that page when asking your question, you might get better responses.